# What is the best way to install (or compile, or emulate) ubuntu calculator on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, calculator

I loved to use calculator on Ubuntu and I don't like calculator on Windows 7.

How is this possible to quickly install Ubuntu calculator on Windows 7?

Comment: seriously.. why? you would need gtk2, a compiler and someone who fixes the code up to run on windows.. only to use another calculator. isnt there any replacement for the calculator that fits your needs AND runs on windows natively?

Comment: @mugen: not necessarily, I have found a solution and now I am checking it. The solution is a virtual machine, in particular Oracle VirtualBox, which (I have to check that) allows to run Ubuntu in a background and present only a control panel of it, so I have the calculator on Windows 7.

Comment: That, Sir, is madness..

Comment: @mugen: yes, you may call it so :-)

Comment: (Expecting many upvotes for *That, Sir, is madness*)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use X forward from virtual machine or from server/separate machine.

[xming](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/) is X emulator for Windows XP/7/2008.

It may be possible to compile Ubuntu calculator for [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/). For example GTK2 is already compiled, and easily installed with Cygwin.

Comment: +1, found your suggestion also nice

Comment: @Tim: good thing with X forward (even from your virtual machine) is that then application acts as native Windows software (so it's in your task bar, you can alt+tab to it etc).

Comment: The same thing is possible with VirtualBox. You are the closest to the answer, so I mark yours as a solution

Answer (score 2):

If the ubuntu calculator is available for KDE, you could try this http://windows.kde.org/. I tried it with some KDE software like amarok, and it worked fine for me.

Comment: +1, thanks for the answer. However, virtual machine brings lots of other applications together so I have chosen that solution.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the XForward: Oracle VirtualBox, Ubuntu 10.10 and VBoxGuestAdditions for Ubuntu would perfectly suite as well.